# Form Submits to white page?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a form for my register system. When the form submits and there's errors, (like 'Enter a username first!' or 'You must provide a password!') it successfully refreshes the page and shows those errors.

HOWEVER, when the form submits and the user has filled out all of the data, and there is NO errors, the form goes to a white page. I looked in the source, and all that shows is the javascript at the top of my page, but it looks like no PHP/HTML is being executed. What is happening?!

-- EDIT --

Okay, so I turned errors on, and I'm getting stuff like this:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in /home/content/04/7195304/html/header.php on line 54
```

Comment: What does your `form`'s html look like? Are you sending it to the right script (in the `action` attribute), are the values being processed/found by that script..?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the top of the form script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // sometimes it's needed when overridden to Off
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So you can see what the error was when you submitted the form.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant usernamei - assumed 'usernamei' in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 18

Notice: Use of undefined constant passwordi - assumed 'passwordi' in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 19

Notice: Use of undefined constant confirm - assumed 'confirm' in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 20

Notice: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 21 
are the errors

Comment: You must check your HTML, find the `<form` and add the attribute: `method="POST"`, assuming you are using POST instead of GET. This should fix your problem.

Comment: usernamei is not a php variable, it is the name of an HTML input element. And yes, I do have method="POST"

Answer (score 1):

An error is occurring partway through the page, and you have error reporting disabled. Enable it and/or check your error log.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you forget a '$' in front of the variable 'username'.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* because you refer to some data as $_POST[username], instead of $_POST['username'], change that.